# JFrame size decreasing

Tags: java, resize

I need your help in java 1.4.
How can I prohibit JFrame decreasing.
In java 5 or 6 I just:

```
new JFrame("TEST").setMinimumSize(...);
```

But how in java 1.4? That code does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4320050) which was fixed in mustang. Take a look at the bug details for possible workarounds that you can try in 1.4.